# Inconsistent Mount Permissions

Tags: permissions

I have two SSD's with an ext4 filesystem on them.  When I mount sda1 onto /mnt/old-samsung-830 it changes the owner and group of the /mnt/old-samsung-830 directory from root:root to jim:jim.  However, if I umount sda1, and mount sdb1 onto the same directory, the owner and group remains as root.  I cannot explain this behavior & want someone to explain why/how this is happening.  Here is the example:

```
### **Note the two disks are unmounted** ###
$ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk  
└─sda1                8:1    0 223.6G  0 part  
sdb                   8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                8:17   0 238.5G  0 part  

### **Note the permissions of the old-samsung-830 directory ** ###
[jim@computer mnt]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Feb  2 19:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Feb  2 13:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  2 19:14 old-samsung-830
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  2 18:59 storage

### **Time to mount sda1.  Notice the owner and group has changed to jim** ###
[jim@computer mnt]$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 old-samsung-830
[jim@computer mnt]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 Feb  2 19:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root  root  4096 Feb  2 13:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x 17 jim jim 4096 Feb  2 19:00 old-samsung-830
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Feb  2 18:59 storage

### **Time to unmount this, and try the other drive in the same directory** ###
[jim@computer mnt]$ sudo umount /dev/sda1 
[jim@computer mnt]$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 old-samsung-830
[jim@computer mnt]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Feb  2 19:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Feb  2 13:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb  2 19:16 old-samsung-830
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  2 18:59 storage
[jim@computer mnt]$
```

This is a very fresh Ubuntu install, and I have only got basic stuff (i.e. no fancy fstab or facl's) working on the PC.  I just want someone to explain how it's possible that when sda1 is mounted, it changes the permissions of the folder to jim:jim, but then when sdb1 is mounted on the same directory, it stays as root.  How is this possible?

I ultimately would love all my drives to mount and use jim:jim (just like when sda1 was mounted).  But I don't understand how or why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not change the permissions of the subdirectory.

When you mount a filesystem onto a mountpoint, the original mountpoint becomes inaccessible and its name refers to the mounted filesystem. So, after

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 old-samsung-830
```

the name `./old-samsung-830` no longer refers to your subdirectory, but to the mounted filesystem.

In your case, it looks that one of the filesystems is owned by `jim:jim` and the other by `root:root`. That's perfectly natural. If you don't like it, you can always `sudo chown -R` on the mounted filesystem.

(Pet peeve: *Folders* are the pretty pictures displayed in a GUI. The structures in the filesystem are *directories*. While most folders do indeed correspond to directories, this is not always the case; the GUI can, and does, create and manage folders which do not correspond to filesystem directories.)

Comment: Thanks.  I just don't understand how a filesystem has an owner that's all.  I thought permissions were assigned to directories and files, not the actual underlying ext4 filesystem.

Comment: @johnsmith: The root directory of a filesystem is a directory like any other directory. It has an owner and file mode bits just like any other directory. When you mount a filesystem, the name of the mountpoint refers to the root directory of that filesystem, and you see the owner and mode of that directory.